# How to retrive data from database using json in codeginter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Please i am trying to retrieve data form database using json in my codeingter application

Here is my model code

```
 public function getJsonFiles()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('zd_files');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

here is my controller code

```
//* Fetching uploaded files jsson
    public function getFilesJson()
    {
        $data = $this->Extra_model->getJsonFiles();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

here is my javascript code

```
$.ajax({                                      
      url: '<?php base_url(); ?>getFilesJson',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var id = data[0];              //get id
        var vname = data[1];           //get name
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // 3) Update html content
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); //Set output element html
      } 
    });
```

here my view file code

```
<div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced</div>
```

it return this result

> id: [object Object] name: undefined

Also i try to view the controller via the direct link and is echo this result

> [{"file_id":"2","file_name":"1967761.png"}]

Please help.

Comment: In model code, you can get single data by return $query->row_array();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly capture the values in the success callback of your AJAX.

```
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var id = data[0].file_id;              //use file_id along with 0  index
        var vname = data[1].file_name;           //use file_name along with 0 index
.
.
.
.
```